# In DES : Matsui's notation(LC) vs Biham's notation(DC)

Tags: cryptanalysis, des, linear-cryptanalysis, notation

I'm doing linear attack for 8 rounds DES. And I just wondering about the difference between Matsui's notation and Biham's notation. In Matsui's paper, numbers bits from 0 to 63 from right to left. In contrast, Biham numbers bits from 1 to 64 form left to right (Because of this, P-permutation, S-box, E-permutation, IP, IPinv.. all of them are differed as well).

I encrypted this plaintext through DES cipher(16rounds), and I got the result. This code is done by Biham's notation.
Plaintext : a57be5d89bedd673
Ciphertext : f6f43bfa4709a33b

**My question is that If I use DES code made by matsui's notation(Sbox, P-permu, E.. all different), is the result same with above one?**

I'm doing linear attack for 8 round DES, and I got stuck about notation.

Comment: The result should be same, otherwise it will not be DES. you should always check yous implementation for correctness by the officially provided Test Vectors.